# Почему не сохраняется картинка в кеше?

Tags: html, php, img

Отображаю на странице картинки с помощью РНР-срипта с постоянной ссылкой вида:

```
<img src="get_jira_image.php?url=aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL3NlY3VyZS91c2VyYXZhdGFyP293bmVySWQ9YWxleC12JmF2YXRhcklkPTEwNTAx" />
```

но они не кешируются в браузере хром, в отличии от остальных и грузятся каждый раз заново. В чем причина такого поведения?

Comment: смотрите заголовки которые php возвращает 
наверняка есть:

    Cache-Control: no-cache 
    Expires: "текущее время"

Comment: Удалил эти заголовки, теперь приходят следующие:

Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 09 Jun 2013 21:03:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=i1kbl16jud39sumr2aocv7qs51; path=/

но изображения всеравно не кешируются

пробовал задавать заголовок "Cache-Control: private"  не помогло также...

Comment: посмотрите на статические ресурсы какие хедеры, выставьте те-же

Comment: Я сонный, потому решение сейчас искать не буду. Скажу раз: из-за этой "особенности" хромушки я перепиливал флэш-приложение(понадеялся на браузерный кэш); и два: кэширование хрома - анекдот и страшный сон в одном экзешнике. 

Весьма вероятно, решение будет в 2-5 дополнительных заголовках специально для хромушки. Или не будет)

Comment: хм... установил точно такие же хедеры как и в статической картинке, кеширование судя по chrome://cache/ есть, но неправильное. Т.е. по сути при повторной загрузке старницы картинки грузятся не из кеша, а из сервера... 
И почему то с разными хедерами сохраняются в кеш статическая и динамическая картинка: http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/4449/2013061063024.png   http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/8347/2013061063044.png